# Operator similar to exhaustMap but that remembers the last skipped value from the source and executes it in the end

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

I need an operator similar to `exahustMap`, but which remembers the last skipped observable and executes it after the current observable completes.

For example, considering the marble diagram for `exhaustMap`:

[image: exhaustMap marble diagram]

In my case, after the blue values are emitted, it will be followed by three values of 50. Of course, in this case it looks just like `concatMap`, but if there were also a 4 between 3 and 5, it would not reflect in the output.

I've managed to write my own operator similar to how `exhaustMap` is implemented:

```
function exhaustLatestMap<T, R>(project: (value: T) => Subscribable<R>): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
    return source => new Observable<R>(observer => 
        source.subscribe(new ExhaustLatestMapOperatorSubscriber(observer, project)));
}

class ExhaustLatestMapOperatorSubscriber<T, R> implements Observer<T> {

    constructor(
        private observer: Subscriber<R>,
        private project: (value: T) => Subscribable<R>) { }

    innerSub: AnonymousSubscription = null;
    latestValue: T;

    next(value: T) {
        this.processNext(value);
    }

    error(err) {
        this.observer.error(err);
    }

    complete() {
        this.observer.complete();
    }

    private processNext(value: T) {
        this.latestValue = value;
        if (!this.innerSub) {
            this.innerSub = this.project(value).subscribe({
                next: v => this.observer.next(v),
                error: err => {
                    this.observer.error(err);
                    this.endInnerSub(value)
                },
                complete: () => {
                    this.endInnerSub(value);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private endInnerSub(value: T) {
        this.innerSub.unsubscribe();
        this.innerSub = null;
        if (this.latestValue !== value) {
            this.processNext(this.latestValue);
        }
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to implement it just by reusing and combining existing operators. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to implement it using just the built-in factories and operators. However, AFAICT, it cannot be done without managing some per-subscription state.

Fortunately, the `defer` factory function makes managing per-subscription state relatively straightforward and safe. And, in addition to helping manage per-subscription state, `defer` can be used as a mechanism for being notified of when an observable is subscribed to.

An alternative implementation:

```js
const {
  concat,
  defer,
  EMPTY,
  merge,
  of
} = rxjs;

const {
  delay,
  mergeMap,
  tap
} = rxjs.operators;

const exhaustMapLatest = project => source => defer(() => {
  let latestValue;
  let hasLatestValue = false;
  let isExhausting = false;
  const next = value => defer(() => {
    if (isExhausting) {
      latestValue = value;
      hasLatestValue = true;
      return EMPTY;
    }
    hasLatestValue = false;
    isExhausting = true;
    return project(value).pipe(
      tap({ complete: () => isExhausting = false }),
      s => concat(s, defer(() => hasLatestValue ?
        next(latestValue) :
        EMPTY
      ))
    );
  });
  return source.pipe(mergeMap(next));
});

const source = merge(
  of(0).pipe(delay(0)),
  of(1000).pipe(delay(1000)),
  of(1100).pipe(delay(1100)),
  of(1200).pipe(delay(1200)),
  of(2000).pipe(delay(2000))
);

source.pipe(
  exhaustMapLatest(value => merge(
    of(`${value}:0`).pipe(delay(0)),
    of(`${value}:150`).pipe(delay(150)),
    of(`${value}:300`).pipe(delay(300))
  ))
).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

There are a couple of behavioural differences between this implementation and yours:

- This implementation uses a `hasLatestValue` flag rather than an equality check, so if the latest value is equal to the initial value, it is still projected.
- With this implementation, if a subscriber to the resultant observable unsubscribes, any subscription to a projected observable will be unsubscribed, too. With your implementation, the inner subscription will remain subscribed - AFAICT - until the projected observable completes or errors.

I'm not advocating that it should be implemented this way. The answer is just to show an alternative implementation.